# Videobox and Lightbox conflicts(not working on same page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am using videobox (from http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/) and lightbox 2 (from http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)
on same page.
First i have successfully implemented lightbox for all images on my page.
Then on same page ,when i applied(or included) JS files for videobox,both lightbox and videobox not working.

Anybody has any idea?
is this js file conflict like mootools.js (from videobox) and prototype.js (from lightbox) ?
or any other reason??

Answer (score 0):

Open the Error Console on your favorite browser (Ctrl+Shift+J in firefox). Check what error it's throwing. If it is indeed a conflict between Prototype and Mootools, use Protosafe to remove the global scope of prototype so that you can use other third party libraries along with it. Here's a link http://ajaxian.com/archives/protosafe-eases-compatibility-for-prototype

P.S: I would suggest you to use one library. There are a lot of tools for Prototype which can help you load images or videos in a lightbox. Google them, you'll find them.